# How to Designate Keyword(s) in a Sentence to Act as a Password (Wildcards)

Tags: javascript, passwords, prompt

I really like the look and feel of the script below. The script works great as long as I'm looking for the user to enter a specified word into the password prompt. But, what I've been trying to do and still keep this look and feel is for the specified password section of the script to use WILDCARDS in addition to the specified word or words. I've tried || and && and a bunch of other suggestions from searching the web but can't seem to find how to make the part of the script that looks for the specified word as the correct password to use not only the specified words but to also allow the user to enter other words into the password prompt. Example: The password prompt appears asking the user to type a sentence - and within the users typed sentence, the script is looking for those specified "keywords" and if they are included within the sentence then the script sees this as the correct "keywords" or specified words or correct passwords have been entered and the script gives the message "that is correct" and takes the user to the designated page. Does anyone know how or if this script below can include a wildcard? Example of how CODE might look... if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "* shake * the * salt *"). Example of what user might type in the prompt.... i would shake all the salt out. So, as long as the users sentence contains the words "shake" and "the" and "salt", the script sees it as the correct password and allows user to continue. Please help. I'm just getting involved with JS. Thanks!

```
    <SCRIPT>
    function passWord() {
    var testV = 1;
    var pass1 = prompt('Type What You Do Next',' ');
    while (testV < 3) {
    if (!pass1); 
    if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "shake") {
    alert('That Is Correct');
    window.open('http://url3.org/webpage4.html','_self','_top');
    break;
    } 
    testV+=1;
    var pass1 = 
    prompt('That Is Not Correct - Focus And Try Again',' ');
    window.open('http://url3.org/webpage5.html','_self','_top');
    }
    if (pass1.toLowerCase()!=" " && testV ==3);
    } 
    </SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the initial password, you could construct a regular expression and replace the `*`s with matches for any number of characters:

```js
function passWithWildcardToRe(pass) {
  // with the `i` flag, no need to call `.toLowerCase()` first:
  return new RegExp(pass.split('*').join('.*'), 'i');
}
const pass1 = "* shake * the* salt *";
const re = passWithWildcardToRe(pass1);
console.log(re.source);
console.log(re.test('i would shake all the salt out'));
console.log(re.test('i would wash all the salt out'));
```

Note that your `i would shake all the salt out` has only one space between `the` and `salt`, while your original `pass1` has `the * salt`, which wouldn't match, so I changed the original `pass1` to `"* shake * the* salt *"`.

Comment: i've been racking my brain researching your suggestion and my original code but can't figure out how to implement it into my code to still keep the look and function of my original code but with the added function of succeeding when anything is typed in as the answer if the answer contains any of the specified "keywords" and fails if anything is typed in as the answer which doesnt contain any of the "keywords". my low level knowledge is the problem. i've only been able to get it to either accept anything, including no entry, as correct or it accepts anything as incorrect.

Comment: to clear up any confusion, I'll try to explain it more clearly. my original code, listed above, works by prompting the user to type their answer. if their answer matches the "keyword", "shake", then the user gets to webpage4 and if it doesnt then the user gets to webpage5. what i would like is this; the user gets prompted to type a sentence as their answer and if the "keyword" is found within the sentence answer then the user gets to webpage4 and if it doesnt then the user gets to webpage5. so im assuming the part of the code that specifies the "keyword" needs to be able to use "wildcards"???

Comment: Just take the initial keyword string with wildcards (such as `shake * the* salt`), then transform it into a regular expression as in the answer. Then, instead of `if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "shake")` in your original code, test against the created regular expression instead: `if (re.test(pass1))`

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you for the reply. I will work on it after work later tonight and post back.

Comment: okay, so as i mentioned previously, I'm a newbie. I've tried researching and testing your suggestions, which I truly appreciate, but am unable to get it working. Your initial answer and then your last comment really compounded my confusion. So this confusion and not being able to figure out where to place your suggestions within the existing code so it functions within the prompt for answer has brought me to a stand still. can you possibly explain in deeper detail how i can apply your suggestions to the existing code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: i;m hoping i got it working the way you had intended for me to, so i got it working to my satisfaction, me being a newbie it took me some time to research all the commands and structures needed, so the following is the resulting script, how it works is like this; a pre-programmed password made up of  specific key words is set and is unknown to the user, the user is prompted to enter an answer consisting of a sentence, if the sentence contains the key words then the user is allowed to continue, my next comment contains the script.

Comment: <SCRIPT>
function passWithWildcardToRe(pass) {
 return new RegExp(pass.split('*').join('.*'), 'i');
 }
 const pass1 = "*specifickeywordhere*specifickeywordhere*";
 const re = passWithWildcardToRe(pass1);
 console.log(re.source);
 console.log(re.test('possiblesentenceherewithabovementionedkeywords'));
 console.log(re.test('possiblesentenceherewithabovementionedkeywords'));
</SCRIPT>

Comment: <SCRIPT>
function passWord() {
 var testV = 1;
 var pass1 = prompt('Type What You Do Next',' ');
 while (testV < 3) {
 if (!pass1);
 if (re.test(pass1)) {
 alert('That Is Correct');
 window.open('http://websiteurlhere/webpagenamehere.html','_self','_top');
 break;
 } 
 testV+=1;
 var pass1 = 
 prompt('That Is Not Correct - Focus And Try Again',' ');
 window.open('http://websiteurlhere/webpagenamehere.html','_self','_top');
 }
 if (pass1.toLowerCase()!=" " && testV ==3);
 } 
</SCRIPT>

Comment: sorry i had to break the script into two comment windows. so i think that's what you suggested i do, and it does seem to work the way i wanted, so cheers to you buddy! Thanks for helping me out with that! Greatly appreciated! Hope it helps others!